# Center unordered list in div with <br> within

Tags: css, html

There are many similar questions, but none have exactly my case, mainly because I have the `<br>` tag inside the list.
I need the code for an e-mail template, therefore I can not use bootstrap or something like it.

I just need to center the social media links at the bottom to make them at the center of the page and keep things as responsive as possible. 
Here's a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/w5dtvs9h/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial;">
    <div style="max-width: 80%; margin: auto;">
    <div style="max-width: 100%; margin: auto;">
<a href="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"><img style="display: block; margin: auto;" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"> </a> </div>
<div>Your thoughts mean a lot to us. Your reviews help us learn what we are doing well, what we need to work on, and what we can do to make your experience with Our Company even better. </div>

<div> <span style="font-weight: bold;">Step 1: Follow the links or any (OR ALL!) of the review sites below </span><br><br> 
Click the buttons below to go to that site and provide your review.</div>

<div><span style="font-weight: bold;">Give us a rating and review. </span> <br><br>
Choose a star rating and provide your comments.</div>
<h3 style="text-align: center;">THANK YOU!</h3>
<hr>

<div style="width: 100%; margin: auto;">
    <ul style="margin: auto; width: 100%;">
        <li style="float: left; list-style:none; margin: auto; margin-right:5%; "><img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" style="max-width: 50px; max-height: 50px;display: block; margin: auto;"><br> Google</li>
        <li style="float: left; list-style:none; margin: auto; margin-right:5%; "><img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" style="max-width: 50px; max-height: 50px;display: block; margin: auto;"><br> Google</li>
        <li style="float: left; list-style:none; margin: auto; margin-right:5%; "><img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" style="max-width: 50px; max-height: 50px;display: block; margin: auto;"><br> Google</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Paulie_D thanks. I didn't know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a table, place two `<td>` with `width:20%;` at the sides, and set `text-align:center;` for all, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/w5dtvs9h/5/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body style="font-family: Arial;">
 <div style="max-width: 80%; margin: auto;">
 <div style="max-width: 100%; margin: auto;">
<a href="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"><img style="display: block; margin: auto;" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"> </a> </div>
<div>Your thoughts mean a lot to us. Your reviews help us learn what we are doing well, what we need to work on, and what we can do to make your experience with Our Company even better. </div>

<div> <span style="font-weight: bold;">Step 1: Follow the links or any (OR ALL!) of the review sites below </span><br><br> 
Click the buttons below to go to that site and provide your review.</div>

<div><span style="font-weight: bold;">Give us a rating and review. </span> <br><br>
Choose a star rating and provide your comments.</div>
<h3 style="text-align: center;">THANK YOU!</h3>
<hr>

<table width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="20%"></td>
  <td style="text-align:center;">
  <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" style="max-width: 50px; max-height: 50px;display: block; margin: auto;"><br> Google
  </td>
  <td style="text-align:center;"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" style="max-width: 50px; max-height: 50px;display: block; margin: auto;"><br> Google</td>
  <td style="text-align:center;"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" style="max-width: 50px; max-height: 50px;display: block; margin: auto;"><br> Google</td>
  <td width="20%"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

also, with table you go safe on html emails.

Comment: I dislike using tables since I read somewhere that they're a bit discouraged since they're becoming outdated, and I usually use bootstrap, but now I can not use bootstrap, was thinking to still avoid tables, but looks like it is inevitable. Thank you very much!

Comment: Tables are still the best thing perhaps to use on html emails, unfortunately the whole email code system is inconsistent and outdated af, so is a common rule to use the oldschool html for it. please consider upvoting it if you found it useful. cheers

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the explanation! I tried upvoting, but I do not have enough reputation for it to show publicly. I guess it will show after I get enough reputation, because the notification said that the upvote still gets recorded. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same layout without changing it to a table and only changing the style:

```
<div>
<ul style="margin: auto;display: flex;justify-content: center;">
    <li style="list-style:none;margin-right:5%;"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" style="max-width: 50px; max-height: 50px;display: block; margin: auto;"><br> Google</li>
    <li style="list-style:none;margin-right:5%;"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" style="max-width: 50px; max-height: 50px;display: block; margin: auto;"><br> Google</li>
    <li style="list-style:none;margin-right:5%;"><img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" style="max-width: 50px; max-height: 50px;display: block; margin: auto;"><br> Google</li>
</ul> 
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w5dtvs9h/6/

Comment: It works in a browser, but not sure if flexbox is compatible with most email clients yet. thank you!